# How to extend struts 2 tag?

Tags: struts2, custom-tags

I want to extend Struts 2 s:select tag.
Can somebody explain step required to do the same.
Also if there is any hook or implementation available in Struts2 framework for the same

Comment: What exactly you want to do with `<s:select>` tag?

Comment: I want to write a kind of wrapper to this tag where i can write custom functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by examining the freemarker templates (default is freemarker but it can be velocity or some other template engine). See http://mikeski.net/site/node/16.

If that is not enough for you then you could extend or create your own implementation of select tag. http://joshuajava.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/creating-custom-components-with-struts-2/

Comment: Perfect, that really solved the problem.Both the examples are very illustrative.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can change the *freemarker* template as you need and extend `org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.SelectTag` [class](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ui/SelectTag.html).

Check this [article](http://bodez.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/customising-struts2-jsp-tags/) to start with.